# Appending columns to awkward.Table

Tags: awkward-array

I am trying to append new columns to an existing awkward Table. The README said that this is possible, but I can't find the way. For example I have a table

```
df = awk.Table(
                p = ppkf2,
                th = thetakf2,
                ph = phikf2,
                eb = beam)
```

And I want to add two columns to it, to have for example

```
df_new = awk.Table(
                p = ppkf2,
                th = thetakf2,
                ph = phikf2,
                eb = beam,
                eton = eton,
                ptrt = ptrt)
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: you tried `df['eton'] = eton` ?

Comment: Hm. Strange. I tried it previously, but it didn't work. I am trying to reproduce those cases to understand why. But in my case now it works, thank you.